# How to make IPython notebook matplotlib plot inline

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython, data-visualization

I am trying to use IPython notebook on MacOS X with Python 2.7.2 and IPython 1.1.0.

I cannot get matplotlib graphics to show up inline.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

I have also tried `%pylab inline` and the ipython command line arguments `--pylab=inline` but this makes no difference.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 500)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x**2))
plt.title('A simple chirp')
plt.show()
```

Instead of inline graphics, I get this:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x110b9c450>
```

And `matplotlib.get_backend()` shows that I have the `'module://IPython.kernel.zmq.pylab.backend_inline'` backend.

Comment: your code snippet should not produce `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x110b9c450>` but `<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x94f9320>` (because your last line is printing a title). Anyway, your code (with %matplotlib inline and plt.show()) works as expected on windows

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, but they don't work for me.  I still get the above output with no inline graphics.  Do you have any troubleshooting advice?

Comment: no clue. Same python, same ipython (and same backend) but on windows, and it works.... I suppose plot is working for you when not inline, right ?

Comment: without the `%matplotlib inline`, the kernel stays busy permanently and I get no output.  It has to be killed.  This is trying to use the `MacOSX` backend but I guess it cannot be opened for some reason.  When not using ipython notebook, the MacOSX backend for matplotlib works just fine.

Comment: I had an identical symptom but it turned out I had installed a 32 bit version of Canopy on OSX 10.8.  Reinstalling with the 64 bit version fixed it.

Comment: Just came across this, one other thing to make sure: All those commands must be on the same input. Not separate. (So use shift+enter instead of enter for newline). When all ran together I get the plot

Comment: Fix once in the startup configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: Support for `--pylab` command line parameter has been removed. So you should use `%pylab inline` in the notebook instead.

Answer (score 1232, accepted):

I used `%matplotlib inline` in the first cell of the notebook and it works. I think you should try:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

You can also always start all your IPython kernels in inline mode by default by setting the following config options in your config files:

```
c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib=<CaselessStrEnum>
  Default: None
  Choices: ['auto', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'inline', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'osx', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'tk', 'wx']
  Configure matplotlib for interactive use with the default matplotlib backend.
```

Comment: I would mark this as the right answer. The alternative `--pylab inline` works, but greets you with the following warning:

_Starting all kernels in pylab mode is not recommended,
    and will be disabled in a future release.
    Please use the %matplotlib magic to enable matplotlib instead.
    pylab implies many imports, which can have confusing side effects
    and harm the reproducibility of your notebooks._

Comment: @eNord9 @mightwolf: I'm learning to using iPython (and Python programming instead of Matlab); what does `import matplotlib' do versus `import matplotlib as [name]'? Forgive for simplistic comment

Comment: @eNord9 @mightwolf: and also how does this compare to `from matplotlib import mpl'.

Comment: @TSGM The best explanation I've seen for your question is: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: Thanks @eNord9.  I just tested your commands since it's been a while with updates and all.  Now everything works fine on Python 2.7.9 and IPython 3.1.0.

Comment: I needed to put the "%matplotlib inline" first in the cell of the block that had "import matplotlib" in it.  If I put it in a separate first cell, it did not seem to apply to the import.   Thanks.

Comment: Relevant thread: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2015-July/016631.html

Comment: For the record, to undo this and switch back to the pop-up, you need to restart the notebook (and comment out the line in your code).

Comment: Actually, you may wish to edit this to say `%matplotlib notebook`

Answer (score 241):

If your matplotlib version is above 1.4, it is also possible to use

IPython 3.x and above

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

older versions

```
%matplotlib nbagg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Both will activate the [nbagg backend](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#the-nbagg-backend), which enables interactivity.

[image: Example plot with the nbagg backend]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'`. Any idea how to get interactive Retina figures?

Comment: Hmm...I don't really have too much expertise with retina figures. The only thing I stumbled upon was [this link](https://gist.github.com/minrk/3301035), but it may be deprecated. If more people are wondering about the same, I link your SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193328/is-there-a-way-to-generate-retina-graphs-using-matplotlib), and wish you good luck with the answers there. Best

Comment: This answer is underrated. `%matplotlib notebook` provides the better visualization than `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: using `%matplotlib notebook` does not work (kind of shows something, then blank) on jupyter notebook 4.1.1 / ubuntu 16.04 / chrome, `%matplotlib inline` does show images, but they come after the markdown text, not literally "inline".

Comment: Strange, did you experience the same in jupyter notebook 4.3.0?
I just checked, and it works good with notebook 4.3.0/ mint 18/chrome (Python 3.5.2, IPython 5.1.0).

Comment: With notebook backend: `JavaScript output is disabled in JupyterLab` , have to `launch Classic Notebook`

Comment: Plots with `%matplotlib notebook` can have axes or legends cut off: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9163

Comment: If you tried `%matplotlib inline` first and then switch to `%matplotlib notebook`, you might get empty result. Restart the kernel and run again.

Answer (score 102):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Magic Line :D

See: [Plotting with Matplotlib](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb).

Comment: @BradleyKreider Not dead yet. Alternatively, you can visit ipython repo on github, go into 'example' folder, find '
Plotting with Matplotlib' notebook.

Answer (score 26):

Use the `%pylab inline` magic command.

Comment: No longer: "ipython notebook --pylab inline
[E 15:01:18.182 NotebookApp] Support for specifying --pylab on the command line has been removed.
[E 15:01:18.182 NotebookApp] Please use `%pylab inline` or `%matplotlib inline` in the notebook itself."

Answer (score 16):

To make matplotlib inline by default in Jupyter (IPython 3):

1. Edit file `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`
2. Add line `c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'inline'`

Please note that adding this line to `ipython_notebook_config.py` would not work.
Otherwise it works well with Jupyter and IPython 3.1.0

Answer (score 12):

I have to agree with foobarbecue (I don't have enough recs to be able to simply insert a comment under his post):

It's now recommended that python notebook isn't started wit the argument `--pylab`, and according to Fernando Perez (creator of ipythonnb) `%matplotlib inline` should be the initial notebook command.

See here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb

Answer (score 9):

I found a workaround that is quite satisfactory.  I installed [Anaconda Python](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/index.html) and this now works out of the box for me.

Answer (score 7):

I did the anaconda install but matplotlib is not plotting

It starts plotting when i did this

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when I was running the plotting commands in separate cells in Jupyter:

```
In [1]:  %matplotlib inline
         import matplotlib
         import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
         import numpy as np
In [2]:  x = np.array([1, 3, 4])
         y = np.array([1, 5, 3])
In [3]:  fig = plt.figure()
         <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>                      #this might be the problem
In [4]:  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
In [5]:  ax.scatter(x, y)
Out[5]:  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x12341234>  # CAN'T SEE ANY PLOT :(
In [6]:  plt.show()                                             # STILL CAN'T SEE IT :(
```

The problem was solved by merging the plotting commands into a single cell:

```
In [1]:  %matplotlib inline
         import matplotlib
         import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
         import numpy as np
In [2]:  x = np.array([1, 3, 4])
         y = np.array([1, 5, 3])
In [3]:  fig = plt.figure()
         ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
         ax.scatter(x, y)
Out[3]:  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x12341234>
         # AND HERE APPEARS THE PLOT AS DESIRED :)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate this problem with a syntax mistake, however, `%matplotlib inline` won't resolve the issue.

First an example of the right way to create a plot. Everything works as expected with the imports and magic that [eNord9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3864073/enord9) supplied.

```
df_randNumbers1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))

df_randNumbers1.ix[:,["A","B"]].plot.kde()
```

However, by leaving the `()` off the end of the plot type you receive a somewhat ambiguous non-error.

Erronious code:

```
df_randNumbers1.ix[:,["A","B"]].plot.kde
```

Example error:

```
<bound method FramePlotMethods.kde of <pandas.tools.plotting.FramePlotMethods object at 0x000001DDAF029588>>
```

Other than this one line message, there is no stack trace or other obvious reason to think you made a syntax error. The plot doesn't print.

Comment: This isn't a syntax error--without the `()` to *invoke* `kde`, iPython is telling you what `kde` *is*, namely, a bound method. So in fact from iPython's perspective, this is not an "error" at all, hence why there is no stack trace.

Comment: @KyleStrand Thanks. After re-reading my post what I should have said is: "I thought I had the problem of not getting my plots to show inline using the `%matplotlib inline` command. Really I just forgot to put () on the end of the plot type.  So if everything else fails, look at your parentheses for a mistake."

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) then the `inline` backend doesn't seem to work so you need to specify `widget`/`ipympl` (which you may need to install support for e.g. `pip install ipympl`):

```
%matplotlib widget
```