# Is there a way to generate Retina graphs using 'matplotlib'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, retina-display

Python's `matplotlib` does not generate Retina display quality *LaTeX* text by default. Are there settings or add-on package that generate Retina quality output?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `'Agg'` mode (standard) to create PNG Graphs?

You can create SVG Graphs with Matplot lib which have way better quality using

```
matplotlib.use('svg')
```

Comment: That backend creates an image file, right (where I'm not sure)? I'm looking fro something that will work with 'MacOSX' (launched using `ipython --pylab`).

Comment: I'm guessing that the answer will be that I'm out of luck: That I'll need to prototype figures interactively with bad-looking *LaTeX* and then switch to the 'svg' backend to save higher quality files for use. But what I'd really like is high quality in interactive mode (using the 'MacOSX' backend.

Comment: I found a comment in the docs, maybe it helps: The fonts look terrible on screen. You are probably running Mac OS, and there is some funny business with older versions of dvipng on the mac. Set `text.dvipnghack : True` in your matplotlibrc file.

Comment: Changing `text.dvipnghack` doesn't seem to do anything. Note that fonts in general look fine, it's just *LaTeX* that doesn't since it seems to be rendered as a bitmap (which resolution that's half what it should be to look good on Retina).

Comment: Yes, thats why I posted the `dvipnghack`. This should fix bad looking Text. If it still doesn´t work I don´t know what else to do... you could try to set LaTeX as default Text renderer (`text.usetex : True`) and see if this affects the normal Text. (I guess it does..) Than maybe check if your Tex installation is up-to-date.

Comment: I'm confused about the last comment: wouldn't using *LaTeX* for everything just spread the problem. Regular text (currently, without any changes, and using the 'MacOSX' backend) looks great, it's just *LaTeX* that looks bad.

Comment: This would help to nail down the Error, since LaTeX should look good (better than normal Text) there is something wrong somewhere in your setup, and activating LaTeX for all the Text might help to see where the problem might lie. If all the Text looks bad there is a good chance that something with your latex compiler is wrong. Otherwise it could be a problem with inline latex in matplotlib.

Comment: No effect: In both cases I get the same result with the 'MacOSX' backend. Text looks great, *LaTeX* does not (looks like a half-res bitmap). For comparison, using the 'svg' backend produces excellent results, as does all other *LaTeX* (e.g. using *LyX* or any *TeX* editor).

Comment: Than the problem seem to lie in Mathtex rendering i guess. You could try to set `mathtext.fontset` to `cm` or `stix` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - The OSX backend has a lot of limitations, but is the only interactive backend that doesn't require additional dependencies on OSX.  Have you tried using another interactive backend?  (I'm more curious than anything... I don't know offhand whether the other interactive Agg-based backends have the same limitation on retina screens.)

Comment: @JoeKington: No, I've been trying to avoid the dependencies (which look bad). For now it seems I'll need to live with the limitations when I want interactivity, and then switch to a different, file-based backend when I want good output. Alternatively, I can always get a kind of poor-man's interactivity by just opening files in an SVG viewer (a web browser will do) and manually refreshing after each update to the graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `texmanager.py` you see that it makes the png by a call to `dvipng` and the function that makes the system call to `dvipng`  has an argument for `dpi`

To get higher resolution `TeX` on a per-figure basis for existing figures

```
plt.gcf().canvas.renderer.dpi = what_ever_retina_dpi_is
```

to set it everywhere, you should be able to set the rcparam `figure.dpi` which will be respected when creating new renderers.

I can't test this as I do not have access to a Mac with a Retina display.

Comment: That just increases the size of all text (not just *LaTeX*, but also text that is already looking fine). So non-*LaTeX* looks big and fine, and *LaTeX* looks big and lust as jagged as before.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius are you sure you cleared the tex cache?

Comment: should be located in `~/.matplotlib/tex.cache`

Comment: Yes. Everything is still too large (the larger the setting, the larger it get).

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1958  It seems this is really an osx issue

Comment: Yeah, it seems I need to give up (for now) the idea of seeing Retina -quality output interactively, and use SVG when I'm ready to create something with quality resolution throughout. It's interesting though that the issue is limited to *LaTeX*. I'd expect that's' something that could be (relatively) easily fixed, by simply doubling the resolution of output and resizing it.

Comment: from your other recent question that involves `style` you are clearly running master installed from source ;)  The code involved is in `texmanager.py`,  I agree it should be relatively straight forward to fix (your comment is what I was _trying_ to do, just neglected it would scale everything)...have at it!