# Automatically run %matplotlib inline in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Every time I launch IPython Notebook, the first command I run is

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Is there some way to change my config file so that when I launch IPython, it is automatically in this mode?

Comment: Does 'ipython -pylab' work?

Comment: If so, you can alias ipython to just do that pretty easily.

Comment: `ipython --matplotlib` is better

Comment: Please ignore the **bounty**. The selected answer does work for 5.5.0. I will close the bounty after the mandatory 24-hour period. Sorry about that!

Comment: I bet you spent more time typing this question and trying to implement solution than simply pasting it into begining of your notebook :D

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## The configuration way

IPython has profiles for configuration, located at `~/.ipython/profile_*`. The default profile is called `profile_default`. Within this folder there are two primary configuration files:

- `ipython_config.py`
- `ipython_kernel_config.py`

Add the inline option for matplotlib to `ipython_kernel_config.py`:

```
c = get_config()
# ... Any other configurables you want to set
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = "inline"
```

## matplotlib vs. pylab

Usage of `%pylab` to get inline plotting is [discouraged](https://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.html).

It introduces all sorts of gunk into your namespace that you just don't need.

`%matplotlib` on the other hand enables inline plotting without injecting your namespace. You'll need to do explicit calls to get matplotlib and numpy imported.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

The small price of typing out your imports explicitly should be completely overcome by the fact that you now have reproducible code.

Comment: Thanks.  I had actually seen this config option in the matplotlib docs, but wasn't sure whether it just set the matplotlib backend that would take effect *once you manually called `%matplotlib`* or whether it both set the default backend and *automatically set it up* for use immediately in the iPython environment.

Comment: To add to @Kyle Kelley's edit regarding `matplotlib` vs `pylab`, iPython makes it very easy to automatically execute arbitrary python code every time you launch using Profiles.  I believe it is quite common to have a profile where you automatically do common imports like `import numpy as np; import pandas as pd; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, etc.  NB: `pylab` is **not** the same thing as `pyplot`.  It must have taken me a month to realize that.

Comment: This (as well as SillyBear's answer) stopped working with IPython 3. https://github.com/ipython/docker-notebook/pull/7#issuecomment-54729770 suggests to use "c.IPKernel.matplotlib"... which doesn't work neither.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28970252/514210) worked for me. In IPython 3 there's apparently a new configuration file, `ipython_kernel_config.py`, that contains this option. Make a new profile (`ipython profile create test`) to get a default.

Comment: This option seems to have been renamed to `c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = "inline"`

Comment: Gosh this must be coming up high on Google. Thanks for commenting @tiago. Seems I better put Jupyter centric config here too...

Comment: Can anyone supply the configuration filename and configuration line to set matplot inline by default in jupyter as of December 2015?  I have been looking for hours and cannot get this to work.  Is the name of the file `~/.jupyter/jupyter-notebook-config.py`?  Is the name of the option `c.NotebookApp.matplotlib`

Comment: @ChrisWarth: [None of these settings work for me.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36360015/656912) I'm not sure what the issue is but I expect either the options have changed or the location of the file has changed. I'm trying `c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = "inline"` in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. My goal is to get this working in Jupyter notebooks (only) and leave shell IPython alone.

Comment: Is there a way to just do `%matplotlib` on startup in a similar manner? I am currently doing `get_ipython().magic('matplotlib')` in the startup.py file, which seems like the wrong way of doing this.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want might be to run the following from the command line:

```
ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline
```

If you don't like typing it at the cmd line every time then you could create an alias to do it for you.

Comment: Please change your post to `--matplotlib inline` and remove the --pylab stuff. See this post of an ipython devel why: http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb.html

Comment: One note about `matplotlib=inline`: It will slow down every kernel you launch, regardless of whether you want to use matplotlib.

Comment: This no longer works (at least as of IPython 4). The command line options `--matplotlib` or `--pylab` are ignored.

Comment: The help for Jupyter command-line help says these options are disabled and should use `%pylab` or `%matplotlib` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The setting was disabled in `Jupyter 5.X` and higher by adding below code

```
pylab = Unicode('disabled', config=True,
    help=_("""
    DISABLED: use %pylab or %matplotlib in the notebook to enable matplotlib.
    """)
)

@observe('pylab')
def _update_pylab(self, change):
    """when --pylab is specified, display a warning and exit"""
    if change['new'] != 'warn':
        backend = ' %s' % change['new']
    else:
        backend = ''
    self.log.error(_("Support for specifying --pylab on the command line has been removed."))
    self.log.error(
        _("Please use `%pylab{0}` or `%matplotlib{0}` in the notebook itself.").format(backend)
    )
    self.exit(1)
```

And in previous versions it has majorly been a warning. But this not a big issue because Jupyter uses concepts of `kernels` and you can find kernel for your project by running below command

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/notebookinline/bin/../share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

This gives me the path to the kernel folder. Now if I open the `/Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/notebookinline/bin/../share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json` file, I see something like below

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}",
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

So you can see what command is executed to launch the kernel. So if you run the below command

```
$ python -m ipykernel_launcher --help
IPython: an enhanced interactive Python shell.

Subcommands
-----------

Subcommands are launched as `ipython-kernel cmd [args]`. For information on
using subcommand 'cmd', do: `ipython-kernel cmd -h`.

install
    Install the IPython kernel

Options
-------

Arguments that take values are actually convenience aliases to full
Configurables, whose aliases are listed on the help line. For more information
on full configurables, see '--help-all'.

....
--pylab=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShellApp.pylab)
    Default: None
    Choices: ['auto', 'agg', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'osx', 'pdf', 'ps', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'svg', 'tk', 'widget', 'wx']
    Pre-load matplotlib and numpy for interactive use, selecting a particular
    matplotlib backend and loop integration.
--matplotlib=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib)
    Default: None
    Choices: ['auto', 'agg', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'osx', 'pdf', 'ps', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'svg', 'tk', 'widget', 'wx']
    Configure matplotlib for interactive use with the default matplotlib
    backend.
...    
To see all available configurables, use `--help-all`
```

So now if we update our `kernel.json` file to

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}",
  "--pylab",
  "inline"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

And if I run `jupyter notebook` the graphs are automatically `inline`

[image: Auto Inline]

Note the below approach also still works, where you create a file on below path

**~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py**

```
c = get_config()
c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
```

But the disadvantage of this approach is that this is a global impact on every environment using python. You can consider that as an advantage also if you want to have a common behaviour across environments with a single change.

So choose which approach you would like to use based on your requirement

Answer (score 4):

Create any `.py` file in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` containing

```
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
```

Comment: As of iPython 8.3, the correct format has become `get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')`.

Comment: Thanks @Alper - would you have the link to the documentation by any chance?

Comment: No problem. See https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.run_line_magic and https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.magic

Answer (score 3):

In your `ipython_config.py` file, search for the following lines

```
# c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = None
```

and

```
# c.InteractiveShellApp.pylab = None
```

and uncomment them. Then, change `None` to the backend that you're using (I use `'qt4'`) and save the file. Restart IPython, and matplotlib and pylab should be loaded - you can use the `dir()` command to verify which modules are in the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

In (the current) IPython 3.2.0 (Python 2 or 3)

Open the configuration file within the hidden folder .ipython

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py
```

add the following line

```
c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
```

add it straight after

```
c = get_config()
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Kyle Kelley and @DGrady, here is the entry which can be found in the

`$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py` (or whichever profile you have created)

Change

```
# Configure matplotlib for interactive use with the default matplotlib backend.
# c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib = none
```

to

```
# Configure matplotlib for interactive use with the default matplotlib backend.
c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
```

This will then work in both ipython qtconsole and notebook sessions.