# ipython notebook inline matplotlib not working after upgrade to 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I recently upgraded ipython to 2.0.0 and can't get inline plots to work. If I try

```
%pylab inline
plot([1,2],[1,2])
```

I get the following output:

```
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10ffcf080>]
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: _image_module::readpng:  png_create_read_struct failed
  FormatterWarning,
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x10e77ca58>
```

And in the console, I have the following error:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/0a214dee-3143-4d34-89cb-9d65ce154fe6/shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 322, in wrapper
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 122, in on_message
    self.session.send(self.zmq_stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/session.py", line 646, in send
    stream.send_multipart(to_send, copy=copy)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_multipart'
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Edit: I'm on python 3.4.0, ipython 2.0.0, and matplotlib 1.3.1

Comment: Looks like your ipython install is borked, I suspect because there are some old files hanging around.  I would suggest deleting everything and re-installing.  I would also suggest using virtual environments instead of installing at the system level.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: As the first possibilities, I would remove (or move to other name if you would save it) the ~/.ipython directory if there is one. Perhaps the settings of the previous version causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As tcaswell mentioned, the easiest way of dealing with issues with dependencies of individual python modules is to test them in a virtual environment- effectively giving you a clean install. If nothing else, this helps the debugging process.

- Make a virtual environment called `myenv` by running this in your
  terminal: `$ virtualenv myenv`
- Activate the environment by running from terminal: `$ source
  myenv/bin/activate`.
- Install ipython (the name of your virtualenvironment is now in
  parentheses at your prompt: `(myenv)$ pip install ipython notebook`
- Once you're done with the virtual environment, run `$ deactivate` or
  close your terminal session.

There are a variety of good guides for virtual environments; I'd recommend [starting here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).  If installing within a virtual environment doesn't fix things, there might be a bigger issue. Once you're done using the virtual environment, you can simply delete the folder created with its name (in this case myenv).

And finally, I'd recommend using `%matplotlib inline` over `%pylab inline` as [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook).