# Seaborn plots not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm sure I'm forgetting something very simple, but I cannot get certain plots to work with Seaborn.

If I do:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

Then any plots that I create as usual with matplotlib get the Seaborn styling (with the grey grid in the background).

However, if I try to do one of the examples, such as:

```
In [1]: import seaborn as sns

In [2]: sns.set()

In [3]: df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

In [4]: sns.pairplot(df, hue='species', size=2.5)
Out[4]: <seaborn.axisgrid.PairGrid at 0x3e59150>
```

The pairplot function returns a PairGrid object, but the plot doesn't show up.

I'm a little confused because matplotlib seems to be functioning properly, and the Seaborn styles are applied to other matplotlib plots, but the Seaborn functions don't seem to do anything. Does anybody have any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 564, accepted):

Plots created using seaborn need to be displayed like ordinary matplotlib plots.
This can be done using the

```
plt.show()
```

function from matplotlib.

Originally I posted the solution to use the already imported matplotlib object from seaborn (`sns.plt.show()`) however this is considered to be a bad practice. Therefore, simply directly import the `_matplotlib.pyplot_` module and show your plots with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

If the IPython notebook is used the inline backend can be invoked to remove the necessity of calling show after each plot. The respective magic is

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 68):

I come to this question quite regularly and it always takes me a while to find what I search:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.show()  # <--- This is what you are looking for
```

Please note: In Python 2, you can also use `sns.plt.show()`, but not in Python 3.

### Complete Example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Visualize C_0.99 for all languages except the 10 with most characters."""

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [41, 44, 46, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 55, 55, 55,
     55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58,
     58, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 61,
     61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62,
     62, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65,
     65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66,
     67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 69, 69, 69, 70, 70,
     70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73,
     74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 76, 77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80,
     80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 81, 83, 84, 84, 85, 86, 86, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87,
     87, 87, 88, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 92,
     92, 93, 93, 93, 94, 95, 95, 96, 98, 98, 99, 100, 102, 104, 105, 107, 108,
     109, 110, 110, 113, 113, 115, 116, 118, 119, 121]

sns.distplot(l, kde=True, rug=False)

plt.show()
```

Gives

[image]

Answer (score 28):

To avoid confusion (as there seems to be some in the comments). Assuming you are on Jupyter:

`%matplotlib inline` > displays the plots **INSIDE** the notebook

`sns.plt.show()` > displays the plots **OUTSIDE** of the notebook

`%matplotlib inline` will **OVERRIDE** `sns.plt.show()` in the sense that plots will be shown **IN** the notebook even when `sns.plt.show()` is called.

And yes, it is easy to include the line in to your config:

[Automatically run %matplotlib inline in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook)

But it seems a better convention to keep it together with imports in the actual code.

Comment: For spark notebooks?

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
.
.
.
plt.show(sns)
```

Comment: Why would you want to pass the module to plt.show()?

Answer (score 7):

If you plot in **IPython console** (where you can't use `%matplotlib inline`) instead of Jupyter notebook, and don't want to run `plt.show()` repeatedly, you can start IPython console with `ipython --pylab`:

```
$ ipython --pylab     
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg

In [1]: import seaborn as sns

In [2]: tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

In [3]: sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips) # you can see the plot now
```

Answer (score 4):

My advice is just to give a

`plt.figure()` and give some sns plot. For example

`sns.distplot(data)`.

Though it will look it doesnt show any plot, When you maximise the figure, you will be able to see the plot.

Comment: I forgot to create a figure (`plt.figure()`) before making my lineplot and didn't understand why the plot didn't show up. Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To tell from the style of your code snippet, I suppose you were using IPython rather than Jupyter Notebook.

In this [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9834/#nlsom) on GitHub, it was made clear by a member of IPython in 2016 that the display of charts would only work when "only work when it's a Jupyter kernel". Thus, the  `%matplotlib inline` would not work.

I was just having the same issue and suggest you use Jupyter Notebook for the visualization.

Answer (score 1):

If `g` is a facet.grid object, then try `g.fig` to force the plotting.