# Seaborn: using boxplot cause running out of memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, out-of-memory, boxplot, seaborn

I would like to plot three boxplots for 1, 2 and 3 `weight_cat` values (these are the only distinct values it has). These boxplots should show dependency height on weight category (`weight_cat`).

So I have such a dataframe:

```
print data.head(5)

        Height    Weight  weight_cat
Index                                
1      65.78331  112.9925           1
2      71.51521  136.4873           2
3      69.39874  153.0269           3
4      68.21660  142.3354           2
5      67.78781  144.2971           2
```

The code below finally eats all my ram. This is not normal, I believe:

```
Seaborn.boxplot(x="Height", y="weight_cat", data=data)
```

What is wrong here? This is the link to [manual](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html). Shape of the dataframe is (25000,4). This the link to the [csv file](http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_Dinov_020108_HeightsWeights).

This is how you can get the same data:

```
data = pd.read_csv('weights_heights.csv', index_col='Index')
def weight_category(weight):
    newWeight = weight
    if newWeight < 120:
        return 1

    if newWeight >= 150:
        return 3

    else:
        return 2

data['weight_cat'] = data['Weight'].apply(weight_category)
```

Comment: Is it actually working?

Comment: @Uzzee nope, I mean `boxplot`

Comment: The data=data looks a bit suspicious, did that work before?

Comment: Calling  `Seaborn.boxplot(x = data.Height, y = data.weight_cat)` will cause same problem. I believe this is not the problem

Comment: Are you calling some sort of show() function to bring it to the display?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597116/seaborn-plots-not-showing-up

Comment: @Uzzee Thank you for try, but nothing changed((

Comment: Are you importing matplotlib.pyplot to do this? What matplotlib version do you have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Swap the `x` and `y` column names:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(x="weight_cat" y="Height", data=data)
```

Currently, you are trying to create a chart with as many boxplots as there are different height values (which are 24503).

This worked for me with your data:

[image]

### EDIT

If you want to display your boxplot horizontally, you can use the `orient` argument to provide the orientation:

```
sns.boxplot(x='Height', y='weight_cat', data=data, orient='h')
```

Notice that in this case, the `x` and `y` labels are swapped (as in your question).

Comment: @Rocketq, I've updated my answer with a horizontal orientation example. Check it in case you would like a horizontal boxplot.

Comment: You could also give `weight_cat` a categorical datatype and then the orientation can be automatically inferred.

Comment: The `x`/`y` swap tip was crucial for me! I've spent half a day debugging my script... thank you!