# adding multiple lines to plot without matplotlib (seaborn)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am working on the following code from [this link](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2015/10/17/metropolis-hastings/).
I have a question:
in the mentioned link the following code lead to a plot. But running this code does not plot any thing. what should be added?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn as sns


mus = np.array([5, 5])
sigmas = np.array([[1, .9], [.9, 1]])


def circle(x, y):
    return (x-1)**2 + (y-2)**2 - 3**2


def pgauss(x, y):
    return st.multivariate_normal.pdf([x, y], mean=mus, cov=sigmas)


def metropolis_hastings(p, iter=1000):
    x, y = 0., 0.
    samples = np.zeros((iter, 2))

    for i in range(iter):
        x_star, y_star = np.array([x, y]) + np.random.normal(size=2)
        if np.random.rand() < p(x_star, y_star) / p(x, y):
            x, y = x_star, y_star
        samples[i] = np.array([x, y])

    return samples


if __name__ == '__main__':
    samples = metropolis_hastings(circle, iter=10000)
    sns.jointplot(samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1])

    samples = metropolis_hastings(pgauss, iter=10000)
    sns.jointplot(samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1])
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `plt.show()` The second question should be asked separately.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you. but there is no `plt` in this code.

Comment: @Mr.T Yes I have seen this link before. but its sampling like my question could not be plot. I am new with seaborn. Could you tell me what lines must be added? Thank you

Comment: Oh, sorry. The common convention is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: @Mr.T  Using this again do not plot anything. I don't know why

Comment: Does `plt.plot([0,2,3,1]); plt.show()` generate a graph?

Comment: @Mr.T Yes. I haven't seen this before. I have to use `plt.plot()` and `plt.show()` both together.

Comment: Maybe you should start with [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py) before trying to use seaborn, which is mainly a facade for matplotlib.

Comment: @Mr.T  Yes sure. for using this example I have to use seaborn for the first time in my life.

Answer (score 1):

As reported by @Mr. T and also in [Seaborn plots not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597116/seaborn-plots-not-showing-up), you should add `plt.show()`. `plt` has to be imported from matplotlib.

So your code should read:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mus = np.array([5, 5])
sigmas = np.array([[1, .9], [.9, 1]])


def circle(x, y):
    return (x-1)**2 + (y-2)**2 - 3**2


def pgauss(x, y):
    return st.multivariate_normal.pdf([x, y], mean=mus, cov=sigmas)


def metropolis_hastings(p, iter=1000):
    x, y = 0., 0.
    samples = np.zeros((iter, 2))

    for i in range(iter):
        x_star, y_star = np.array([x, y]) + np.random.normal(size=2)
        if np.random.rand() < p(x_star, y_star) / p(x, y):
            x, y = x_star, y_star
        samples[i] = np.array([x, y])

    return samples


if __name__ == '__main__':
    samples = metropolis_hastings(circle, iter=10000)
    sns.jointplot(samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1])

    samples = metropolis_hastings(pgauss, iter=10000)
    sns.jointplot(samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes I tested it but again the plot did not appear!

Comment: It worked on my side. How do you run your script? Did you get an error ?

Comment: No, It does not contain any error. Just the symbol `>>>` appears.

Comment: Are you using an IPython Notebook? If yes, could you try to run that `%matplotlib inline` in your Notebook?

Comment: I have to use plt.plot() and plt.show() both together. It is the new thing I find :|

Comment: Actually, you should not have to use plt.plot() in your script, just plt.show() should be enough.