# dir(sns) not listing plt

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to use `dir(sns.plt) but this results in an error:

```
dir(sns.plt)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-8072046646b0>", line 1, in <module>
    dir(sns.plt)

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'
```

How do get 'plt' to show up or add it?

Comment: `plt` is the usual alias by which pyplot is imported, i.e. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I also added "pyplot as plt" after import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this posting for more information on plt used with seaborn:
[Seaborn plots not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597116/seaborn-plots-not-showing-up)