# Unable to view Seaborn Plots

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a plot using seaborn with data from an excel sheet on python on Jupiter.
The code I am using is:

```
[In]: import numpy as np
[In]:import pandas as pd
[In]:import seaborn as sns
[In]:import matplotlid.pyplot as plt
[In]:%matplotlib
[In]: df =pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jcree\OneDrive\Documents\Accounting\Applied_Accounting_Principles\Exercises\Data_Analytics\Workbook1.xlsx.xlsx')
[In]: sns.distplot(df['Item Price'])
```

This is where the plot should show up but nothing is happening.
I tried using this solution [Seaborn plots not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597116/seaborn-plots-not-showing-up) but I am unableto get a chart to show.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: anaconda and Jupiter notebook

Comment: Try 'plt.show()'

Comment: When I input that I get an error that says plt not defined