# Plot does not show up after plot.show() is called

Tags: python, seaborn

I cannot get the graph to print using the code below. I tried multiple variations of plt.show() and nothing prints to the console, updated to include all of the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

#!curl -o marathon-data.csv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakevdp/marathon-data/master/marathon-data.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
data = pd.read_csv('marathon-data.csv')
data.head()

# by default pandas loaded the time columns as strings
data.dtypes
data['fina']=pd.to_datetime(data['final'])

data['split_delta']=pd.to_timedelta(data.split, errors='coerce')
data['final_delta']=pd.to_timedelta(data.final, errors='coerce')

data['split_seconds'] = data['split_delta'].dt.total_seconds()
data['split_final'] = data['final_delta'].dt.total_seconds()

data['final_sec']=data['split_final'].astype(int) / 1E9
data['split_sec']=data['split_seconds'].astype(int) / 1E9


with sns.axes_style('white'):
    g = sns.jointplot(x='split_sec', y='final_sec', data=data, kind='hex')
    g.ax_joint.plot(np.linspace(4000, 16000),
                    np.linspace(8000, 32000), ':k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as-is, since `data` is not defined. Also, I'm guessing from `%matplotlib inline` that you're running this in Jupyter Notebook, is that correct?

Comment: try doing `plt.ion()` or `g.show()` or `plt.show(g)` or `plt.show(sns)` maybe? not familiar with what sns returns as `g` but you're definitely calling show on the wrong object...more info here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597116/seaborn-plots-not-showing-up

Comment: maybe bad assumption but didnt think the underlying data would matter, added the full code now

Comment: Also running in Spyder

Comment: Have you tried to run it from a shell? You should remove '%matplotlib inline' and turn 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' into 'import pylab as plt'. Maybe some error is raised...

Comment: By default Spyder shows the plots in the plot section. Probably you're getting your plots, and you can see them with `Ctrl+Shift+G` or View > Panes > Plots. Also, `%matplotlib inline` doesn't work in recent versions of Spyder. Finally, select the "plots" tab.

Comment: Cainã Max Couto-Silva, thats it! I just updated Spyder and was used to running all the graphs through the console vs plots. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default Spyder shows the plots in the plot section. Probably you're getting your plots, and you can see them with Ctrl+Shift+G or View > Panes > Plots. Also, %matplotlib inline doesn't work in recent versions of Spyder. Finally, select the "plots" tab. – Cainã Max Couto-Silva 2 mins ago

This comment answered the question.