# Cannot plot inline with ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm playing with ipython notebook and I got a problem.

This code `%matplotlib inline`helped me to plot inline with the code below.

```
%matplotlib inline 
ax1= plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(df.Close,label="sp500")
ax1.plot(ma,label='50MA')
plt.legend()

ax2=plt.subplot(2,1,2, sharex = ax1)
ax2.plot(df['H-L'],label='H-L')
plt.legend()
```

However, I cannot plot inline with the code below.

```
%matplotlib inline

def single_stock(stock_name):
    df = pd.read_csv('stocks_date_modified.csv',index_col='time',parse_dates=True)
    df = df[df.type == stock_name.lower()]
    _500MA= pd.rolling_mean(df['value'],500)
    ax1= plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    df['close'].plot(label='Price')
    plt.legend()

    ax2= plt.subplot(2,1,2, sharex = ax1)
    _500MA.plot(label='500MA')
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()

single_stock('bac')
```

I got an error message saying

```
UsageError: unrecognized arguments: #this code is to plot inline the notebook
```

Without the `%matplotlib inline`I don't have problem showing the plots but in the popup window.

Could someone help me to solve this?

Comment: is there any difference if you run your notebook with `ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Oh so ipython notebook users type --matplotlib=inline every time when they want the plots to be inline?

Comment: I've posted an answer for your comment :)

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?  You should only need to run the inline magic once per notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your notebook with:

```
ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline
```

And to avoid repetitive typing on everytime you use notebook, you can create a notebook profile [READ HERE](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html#python-config-files).
You can also read this relevant [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook) with regards to how to write your configuration file.

Or if you're using some sort of shortcut key to invoke your notebook (like in Mac/Linux), you can bind the key combinations to run the command above.

Answer (score 7):

If anybody else encounters this error, it seems that you cannot have inline comments on lines that call IPython Magics:

```
In [9]: %matplotlib inline # allows matplotlib to be inline

UsageError: unrecognized arguments: # allows matplotlib to be inline
```

Without the comment, it works just fine:

```
In [9]: %matplotlib inline
```

But yes, loading matplotlib inline at startup with `ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline` is probably a wise move anyway.