# IPython3 automatically config %matplotlib inline

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using IPython 3 / Jupyter, and I want to use the %matplotlib option by default.

In IPython 2, I had the next option on the ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
```

But in IPython 3, this option is not available anymore.

It also disappeared the setting c.InlineBackend.rc, which I used to set up the appearance of charts.

How those options can be set now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please stop changing `ipython_kernel_config` to `ipython_config`, the second one also apply for the pure terminal interpreter where `inline` will not work.  I do mean `ipython_kernel_config`.

Comment: Note that you might need to create a new profile if you're upgrading from IPython 2 - the `ipython_kernel_config.py` file is apparently new in IPython 3.

Comment: Still a working solution for python 3.6.5 and Jupyter QtConsole 4.3.1

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit file `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`
2. Add line `c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'inline'`

You probably don't have this file, so you can create it with this command

`echo "c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'inline'" > ipython_config.py`

Still works well, as of Apr 2017.

Comment: This does work for automatically setting up inline plotting in the IPython Qt console, but running IPython in a terminal produces an error message: `[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | GUI event loop or pylab initialization failed
UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'inline', valid ones are: pyglet, gtk3, qt, tk, wx, osx, qt5, gtk, glut`

Comment: it works if you run  `ipython notebook` (You do get the message when running `ipython`, but that does not start Jupyter)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this works in your case, but you can give it a try:

I am using a custom notebook theme according to this [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Carreau/posts/blob/master/Blog1.ipynb). Basically, I entered: `ipython profile create customcss` in a command-line and modified the custom.css file in  `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom`

Additionally i tried to get rid of my personalizations and imports in the first cell of every notebook by writing a file called `00_my_imports.py` in the folder `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`.

So in your case, you could try to execute the line '%matplotlib inline' at startup