# Configuring Jupyter notebooks for inline Retina Matplotlib figures

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython, retina-display, jupyter-notebook

I want the effect of

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'
```

at the launch of all my Jupyter notebooks, but I can't figure out what the **current** approach is for accomplishing this. There are many answers here and elsewhere, but none that I can find seem to be up to date.

How do I accomplish the above in the **current** versions of Jupyter notebooks (but not IPython generally!): what settings should I apply where is the configuration file I should put them in?

---

I've tried

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = "inline"
c.InlineBackend.figure_formats = set(['retina'])
```

in

```
~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

but this has no effect.

Comment: I think you want an IPython startup file: http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files

Comment: @ThomasK: Does that apply to all of IPython, or just (as desired) to Jupyter  notebooks? What do I put there?

Comment: Startup files apply to IPython however it's started. You put the code you want to run in them.

Comment: @So how does this address the question? What code goes where for Jupyter notebooks (only)?

Answer (score 7):

I have

```
c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
c.InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

in my `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py`.

Comment: Any idea what the relationship is between `ipython_kernel_config.py` (which I don't have) and `ipython_notebook_config.py` (which I do have, but), where these settings seem to have no effect.

Comment: You should have `ipython_kernel_config.py` in your `~/.ipython/profile_default/`. Can you please run `ipython profile create` in your terminal. That should create all the config files. Make sure the lines you wish to take effect are uncommented and that the first uncommented line reads `c = get_config()`.

Comment: That seems to work. But what are the roles now of other files like `ipython_notebook_config.py` (where I set my `NotebookManager` configuration) and `ipython_config.py` where I ([try to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38361607/656912)) set my prompt and (successfully, I think) set `InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines`? Which get used by what (e.g., notebook vs shell) and which are obsolete? Is this documented *anywhere*?

Comment: Glad it worked. I am not entirely sure. You could read all about it here: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html

Comment: As of today, I'm suddenly getting `ValueError: could not convert string to float: figurefigure` when I try to display a figure. This goes away when I remove `c.InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'` from my `ipython_kernel_config.py`.

Comment: Update: went away when I updated from `ipython` 4.0.0 to 5.8.0.