# How do I update my PromptManager settings for IPython 5.0?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, settings

The lines

```
# Output prompt. '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
c.PromptManager.out_template = '{color.Green}Out[{count}]{color.Green} : {color.LightGray}'

# Continuation prompt.
c.PromptManager.in2_template = '{color.Yellow}   .\\D.{color.Green} : {color.LightGray}'

# If True (default), each prompt will be right-aligned with the preceding one.
c.PromptManager.justify = True

# Input prompt.  '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
c.PromptManager.in_template = '{color.Green}In [{count}]{color.LightGreen} : {color.DarkGray}'
```

in my `ipython_config.py` give

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:440: UserWarning: As of IPython 5.0 `PromptManager` config will have no effect and has been replaced by TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class
  warn('As of IPython 5.0 `PromptManager` config will have no effect'
```

but replacing `PromptManager` with `TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class` has no effect.

How do I update my `PromptManager` settings for IPython 5.0?

Comment: Maybe this recent SO question on v5 prompt will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275585/adding-color-to-new-style-ipython-v5-prompt

Comment: @hpaulj: No. I'm looking for what lines go in place of the ones above (and work).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a config object with members as described in the [iPython v5.x](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/api/generated/IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.html) documents.
The example given in the documentation:

```py
# sample ipython_config.py
c = get_config()

c.TerminalIPythonApp.display_banner = True
c.InteractiveShellApp.log_level = 20
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
    'myextension'
]
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'import numpy',
    'import scipy'
]
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = [
    'mycode.py',
    'fancy.ipy'
]
c.InteractiveShell.autoindent = True
c.InteractiveShell.colors = 'LightBG'
c.InteractiveShell.confirm_exit = False
c.InteractiveShell.editor = 'nano'
c.InteractiveShell.xmode = 'Context'

c.PrefilterManager.multi_line_specials = True

c.AliasManager.user_aliases = [
 ('la', 'ls -al')
]
```

Does not mention `prompt_manager` most of which your configuration deals with custom prompts but the section on [custom prompts](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/config/details.html#custom-prompts) does show exactly how to do the sort of thing that you are looking for.

The following is untested code as I do not have a system to hand that can run Python 2.7 & iPython 5:

```py
from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token
import os

class MyPrompt(Prompts):
     def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
         return [(Token, os.getcwd()),
                 (Token.Prompt, ' >>>')]
```