# The exponential distribution didn't show up in the shell

Tags: shell, matplotlib, ipython

Here is a short code :

```
import numpy as np   
from scipy.stats import expon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)
plt.plot(x, expon.pdf(x))
```

When I type that in the shell in using `ipython`, that didn't show up anything while it is supposed to plot the exponential distribution for x between 0 and 10. Could anyone be able to tell me what is the problem here?

I got that, but the plot did show up

```
In [16]: plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x))
Out[16]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fbfe6bc2890>]
```

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** Be aware that I am using Ubuntu 16.10 (Linux distribution).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ... the terminal

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Just bash

Comment: Yes I could. If you install ipython and execute `ipython`, then we can enter import lib and using it normally. Btw, yes I use np (numpy here). You could see the edit of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using IPython. Depending on in which environment you use it, you can create inline plots or plot to a window.

Ipython in Jupyther QtConsole allows to set the inline backend, `%matplotlib inline`.

[image]

In IPython without graphical support, you need to invoke a plotting window using `plt.show()`

[image]

Comment: I am using Jupiter Qtconsole since today. Where did you install `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: It doesn't have to be installed. Does it not work for you?

Comment: I cannot get matplotlib graphics to show up inline with jupyter.

Comment: Everything work with `plt.show()`; I just want to use Jupyter.

Comment: Yes, that is shown in the first image from my answer.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. In Ubuntu, we have configuration file, e.g., `.bashrc`, `.vimrc` and so on. Is there a config file for Jupiter where I could insert the command `%matplotlib inline` where it could be loaded automatically?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook).