# Change default backend for matplotlib in Jupyter Ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

Right now the default backend for matplotlib is `'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'`

I want to switch that to `TkAGG`. I edited the `matplotlibrc` file in

`~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc/`

to add

`backend      : TkAgg`

and It did switch the `backend` for the python but not in `Jupyter`.

For now everytime I start a new notebook in `Jupyter`, I have to do `%matplotlib tk`, isnt there a nice way to make `TkAGG` the default backend in `Jupyter`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is similar to [Automatically run %matplotlib inline in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook), except that you want to automatically use TK backend instead of inline backend.

So the idea is to locate you IPython configuration file. See [configure IPython](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/config.html). It should be

```
/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py
```

If it doesn't yet exist, create it via `> ipython profile create`.

Inside this file locate the setting `c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib` and set it to `"tk"`. It should then look like

```
## Configure matplotlib for interactive use with the default matplotlib backend.
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = "tk"
```

Save the file and restart the kernel.

Comment: this did help. thanks. i went through similar questions but somehow missed this one.