# maplotlib.pyplot.show() works with python but not with jupyter console

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151514/matplotlib-plot-window-wont-appear) and [also this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show). It looks like for me, matplotlib.pyplot.show() shows a figure from python, but not from jupyter console.

`matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()` returns the same matplotlibrc file location for both.

However, when I try to find the backend being used with  `matplotlib.rcParams['backend']` jupyter console tells me -  `'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'`, regardless of which backend I have modified the matplotlibrc file to use.

Python on the other hand, correctly shows the backend I'm using; currently 'TkAgg'.

I installed matplotlib using `python -mpip install -U matplotlib`.

I'm using the following versions:

- Windows 10
- Jupyter console 5.2.0
- Python 2.7.14
- IPython 5.5.0

I can make do with using python, but it would be nice to figure this out for jupyter console as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that `plt.show()` works as expected, also in Juypter.

[image]

This uses the default `'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'` backend. This backend is set by Jupyter, independently of the `rcParams` setting.

You may **set** the backend using `matplotlib.use()`

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

or just using IPython magic `%matplotlib backendname`

```
%matplotlib tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

You may **change** the backend using `pyplot.switch_backend()`

```
plt.switch_backend("TkAgg")
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

or using the same IPython magic

```
%matplotlib tk
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

If you want to set the backend to be used by default, see this question: 
[Change default backend for matplotlib in Jupyter Ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207687/change-default-backend-for-matplotlib-in-jupyter-ipython)