# Error <Figure size 1000x600 with 1 Axes> even with plt.figure () before plt.plot

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the part of my code with the error (that's all related to the graph, but the points:

```
plt.figure (figsize = (10,6))
plt.title ("Alfa x CL")
plt.plot (Alpha,CL, "b",linewidth = 2, label = "Xflr5")
plt.plot (alfa,cl, "r",linewidth = 2, label = "Experimental")
plt.legend (loc = 'upper left')
plt.grid (True)
plt.xlabel ("Alfa")
plt.ylabel ("Cl")
plt.savefig (grafico01) #grafico01 is a variable used before
plt.show ()
```

And it shows the message < Figure size 1000x600 with 1 Axes > instead of the graph (After runing the program again, the graph is shown for some reason)

After searching a lot, I believe the error is on the order I placed the functions, but I have no ideia with one is the right one, everything I found here was about the `plt.figure ()` being after the `plt.plot ()` (with is not the case here)... Any help with the order? Or is it something else?

Comment: That's *not* an error message. It's just the object, that `plt.figure` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in your variables in the plot function like you already have. Try plotting directly on the desired axes using `ax`. It is the preferred way of doing things:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(range(0,10),range(10,0,-1),  'b',linewidth = 2, label = 'Xflr5')
ax.plot(range(0,10),[i*(i**(1/2)) for i in range(0,10)], 'r',linewidth = 2, label = 'Experimental')
ax.set_title('Alfa x CL')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel ("Alfa")
ax.set_ylabel ("Cl")
plt.savefig ('grafico01.png') #grafico01 is a variable used before
plt.show ()
```

For another figure just do:

```
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax2.plot(range(0,10),range(10,0,-1),  'b',linewidth = 2, label = 'Xflr5')
```

just like before.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work... I changed the variables, of course, but I think I did it in the wrong way...

`ax.plot (Alpha,CL,  'b',linewidth = 2, label = 'Xflr5')`
`ax.plot (alfa,cl, 'r',linewidth = 2, label = 'Experimental')`

@Monty

The variables are Alpha and CL for the blue line and alfa, and cl for the red one.

It gave me the same message

Comment: Are you saying that you saw this message again? < Figure size 1000x600 with 1 Axes >

Comment: Yes, I saw this exactly message again @Monty

Comment: Sorry for not seeing this sooner. Does the graph not appear the first time and then appear when you run the second time using the code I posted above? (similar to the behavior you described in the original post?)

Comment: According to this link, the behavior you have might be expected. It is odd that your example above doesn't reproduce the issue though. If adjusting the backend doesn't work, then please provide an example I where I can reproduce the error.

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11745

I suppose I should also ask, are you using Jupyter or an IDE for your code?

Comment: Yes, the code have the same behavior as before, it shows the message, and if I run again, it plots the graph...
I'm using Jupyter, but how do I adjust the backend? Will you need the full code if it fails? @Monty

Comment: In the first cell, have you tried doing the following cell magic?
%matplotlib notebook

Comment: Also check out this for changing the backend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471972/maplotlib-pyplot-show-works-with-python-but-not-with-jupyter-console?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I searched a lot on the internet and found some backend... Thank you! (I used TkAgg) @Monty