# why does matplotlib return an object instead of plotting it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm running this in the current version of Jupyter.

One of my cells contains the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():  
    a_list = list(range(20))
    plt.plot(a_list)  
    plt.show()

main()
```

When I run `kernel > Restart & Run All` the only output I get is a plot figure: `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1bd35aa7a20>` .

When I run the cell directly with the `Run` button, I get the expected plot.

When I move `main()` to its own cell and then run `kernel > Restart & Run All` I get the expected plot.

I would appreciate help in understanding what's going on.

Comment: If you place `%matplotlib inline` at the beginning of your notebook and then run `kernel > Restart & Run All`, do you get the expected plot? (If so, then [here is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21176731/190597) to automatically run `%matplotlib inline` whenever IPython notebook is started.)

Comment: Yes, adding `%matplotlib inline` lets the initial example work as expected. But still, what's going on? Why is that necessary (sometimes)? And how would someone know to do that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I believe the issue here is that there are a number of possible [matplotib backends](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends) available and IPython/Jupyter is not picking the right one / has not been configured to pick the one you desire. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43027980/190597) which has links to the docs.