# Jupyter (IPython) notebook not plotting

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I installed anaconda to use pandas and scipy. I reading and watching pandas tutorials and they all say to open the ipython notebook using

```
 ipython notebook --pylab==inline
```

but when I do that I get a message saying

```
"Support for specifying --pylab on the command line has been removed. Please use '%pylab = inline' or '%matplotlib =inline' in the notebook itself"
```

But that does not work. Then when I try "plot(arange(10))" I get a message saying "name 'plot' is not defined." I trying plotting data from a .csv file and got

```
"matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xebf8b70".
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try `%matplotlib inline` inside the notebook (notice the lack of an `=` sign).

Comment: Try the instructions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-inline-matplotlib-graphics

Answer (score 125):

I believe the pylab magic was removed when they transitioned from IPython to a more general Jupyter notebook.

Try:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Also when you get a message like:

```
"matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xebf8b70".
```

That's just IPython displaying the object.  You need to specify IPython display it.  Hence the matplotlib inline magic.