# Not getting expected output - Plotting Histograms in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, data-visualization, kaggle

I am new to Pandas and I am trying to get the histogram of my data set.
When I am running the same query on Kaggle notebook I am getting my desired output i.e. The histograms appearing, while running the same query on Jupyter notebook shows nothing. Where am I going wrong?
Here's the snippet of my code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\PyWork\kaggle\diabetes.csv')

 #Visualizing Data 
 dataset.hist(figsize=(10,8))
```

The output I am getting is,

```
 array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 
   0x000000634FD88278>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000634FDF5630>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000634FE49240>],
   [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000634FEAD828>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000634FF0A080>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000634FF0A0B8>],
   [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000634FF75EF0>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000006350013320>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000006350076C18>]], 
    dtype=object)
```

Comment: No, this doesn't apply to my problem.

Comment: have you tried running `%matplotlib inline` in an empty cell on jupyter notebook first?

Comment: No, I didn't. And this actually solved it. Thanks

Comment: Found similar discussion- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609600/jupyter-ipython-notebook-not-plotting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out running %matplotlib inline in an empty cell before writing any code solves it. Thanks @MattR for your help!

Comment: I would suggest closing the question, as it has been asked before :)