# Get Matplotlib to show figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I have the following code in my IPython Notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure()
fig.show()
```

After typing this, I see the following:

`<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x192e4ef0>`

How can I get matplotlib to show the empty figure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make ipython notebook inline matplotlib graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-inline-matplotlib-graphics)

Answer (score 2):

it is `plt.show()` and not `fig.show()`