# python syntax error in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using python 3.5, pycharm and getting invalid syntax  at `%matplotlib inline` as output here is my code:

```
import time
import requests
import cv2
import operator
import numpy as np
# Import library to display results


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: are you using `ipython` or `jupyter notebook`? %matplotlib inline` is an ipython magic command, which won't work in other python environments

Answer (score -1):

I think this link may be what you are looking for: [How to make IPython notebook matplotlib plot inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline)

Put the `%matplotlib inline` on the first line. This is useful in the context of using Jupyter notebooks (http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)