# How to run python script to output in html or php same as Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python Notebook and I am having problem with displaying the output to the webpage. It always open a popup window instead of displaying the output in Html form.  Is there a way to put a code in my site and let the python language interpret my code and display the output as html when the page is loaded? or image if it is a graph?. See the sample image below.

[sample screenshot from a website][1]

Currently my code to call python is

```
 <?php 

  $command = escapeshellcmd('python C:\Users\dondell\Downloads\a.py');
  $output = shell_exec($command);
  echo $output;

 ?>
```

This code will print number output to html directly but if the output is image. it will not display but a popup window appear instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make IPython notebook matplotlib plot inline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline)

Comment: No it is not duplicate. I want to show it on my own website not using jupyter at all. I want like this . He can run the code directly to his website.   https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/the-importance-of-preprocessing-in-data-science-and-the-machine-learning-pipeline-ii-centering-scaling-and-logistic-regression#

Comment: How about saving the image to local folder and return its path from python file so that you can use `img` tag and show the image?

Comment: I want to run it like Jupyter but inside my web page.

Comment: The window opening might be a matplotlib plot. If you're trying to do plotting, your Python code will need to save it to a file which your PHP can then serve.

Comment: @DondellBatac Looking at the source code for that tutorial page you linked, it appears to be using something called datacamp-light to embed a jupyter-like notebook.  I found some instructions to get started with it in the github readme: https://github.com/datacamp/datacamp-light which may help.

Comment: @rakslice Your answer is so far the best. But it is not capable of graph presentation like that of jupyther right?. But thanks anyway man.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best you can do is using [NBViewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/). This renders the notebook but you cannot execute it, I believe that executing it is not an easy task