# How can i solve the variable not defined error in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Error in this statement that vectorizer not defined while i already defined it
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(url_list)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get the best response please ask your question with a reproducible example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And include the line before that which has `vectorizer = ...` if it is defined.

Comment: Have you already seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867005/matplotlib-in-jupyter-results-in-variable-is-not-defined

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].