# How to see the plot made in python using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, kaggle

I am following the tutorial http://ahmedbesbes.com/how-to-score-08134-in-titanic-kaggle-challenge.html and following is my code

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
.output_png {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
""")

# remove warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
# ---

import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = 100
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np

pd.options.display.max_rows = 100


data = pd.read_csv('./data/train.csv')

data.head()

data['Age'].fillna(data['Age'].median(), inplace=True)
survived_sex = data[data['Survived']==1]['Sex'].value_counts()
dead_sex = data[data['Survived']==0]['Sex'].value_counts()
df = pd.DataFrame([survived_sex,dead_sex])
df.index = ['Survived','Dead']
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, figsize=(15,8))
```

I dont actually see the plot. How do i see the plot?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `plt.show()` at the end.

EDIT:

Also, you may need to add `%matplotlib inline` as explained here: [How to make IPython notebook matplotlib plot inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline)