# dispaying graph jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, graph

In jupyter notebook I cannot see this graph:

```
feature_importances = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_, index=columns)
feature_importances.sort_values(inplace=True)
feature_importances.plot(kind="barh", figsize=(7,6))
```

I can only see matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xda87c18

Comment: Have you imported `%matplotlib inline` before?

Comment: try `%matplotlib inline`, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19410042/2901002)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have executed a cell starting with this magic:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

This is [now required](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#options) in jupyter, whereas ipython notebook allowed the `--matplotlib` flag when starting the notebook server.