# Jupyter Notebook launches the Python Launcher even if %matplotlib inline is used

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have recently install Jupyter notebook in my MacBook Pro (runnig Mac OS X). But I have some trouble with this notebook now.

When I write some code inside the notebook for `matplotlib` plotting and run the code it just **open my Python Launcher** (instead showing the plot in the notebook.) and I have to **Force quit** this launcher. I cannot understand what is the problem with this new notebook which I install recently.

Then I try to use `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook` at the beginning of my code but it remains the same behavior. In fact, if I only run the single line code `%matplotlib inline` in a new file in jupyter it just launch my **Python Launcher** and immediately my system don't respond and I have to force quite the Python Launcher.

I cannot understand what's the problem with my notebook after the new installation. Please help me.

**Here my system configurations**

jupyter            1.0.0

ipython            7.0.1

matplotlib         3.0.0

**Edit:**

I have installed Python 3 from the website :https://www.python.org/ by downloading the file.

and installed Jupyter Notebook by: `python3 -m pip install --user jupyter`

Should I reinstall them to solve this?
I cannot use my all notebooks that I previously created. Does anyone here can help me ?

**Edit 2**

Just a few minute ago, I uninstall my python3 using `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Python\ 3.7` . and my python3 has been gone from my applications. But still when I type `python3` in my terminal it opens up Python3. I guessed this happens because before the recent installation from python website I install python using `homebrew`. Is it possible that this version of python is still running where as the older version is gone.

In this situation I don't know what to do...Should I uninstall everything related to python3 and install it again to repair the Jupyter notebook. Thank you..

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook via anaconda?

Comment: @yoonghm..No I've installed it by ```python3 -m pip install --user jupyter```

Comment: Perhaps you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline

Comment: @yoonghm..I've seen this before and also I use ```%matplotlib inline``` at starting but it didn't work

Comment: I suspect these libraries are incompatible. I never try, but you may try to debug the portion when plt is shown.  Alternatively use Anaconda instead.

Comment: @yoonghm....Can you tell me ....I just uninstall Jupyter notebook by ```pip-autoremove jupyter -y``` but after that  when I type jupyter notebook on terminal it again opens jupyter notebook. But if I ``pip3 list``` i see all the files related to jupyter has been gone..?

Comment: If you use Linux or Mac, try to type `which jupyter`. If you use Windows, type `where jupyter`.  You can use `pip list` or `pip freeze` to see list of installed packages.  Uninstall them manually.  I believe you have multiple versions of python installed.  I found it hard to maintain python versions and different packages, so I switched to use Anaconda even if it occupies more disk spaces.

Comment: @yoonghm .... thank you for your support.... I just download Anaconda... and now everything is pretty good.... Jupyter notebook and Puthon3.7  both are working fine..