# matplotlib plots only once unless Windows 10 is restarted

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run this code in Spyder or Jupyter Notebook, it runs once only. Afterward, it shows a blank graph without any plotting inside. The code will plot again only if I restart the Windows 10.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

x = np.linspace(0,10,1)
y = np.sin(x)

pl.plot(x,y)
```

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify when it shows a blank graph? Does this mean even after running this code block, it does not plot anything? Also, if you can show a screenshot of your issue, that would be helpful as well. You might also consider the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/19410042/

Comment: You really need to restart *Windows* to make it work again? Closing and re-opening the notebook doesn't work, or restarting Jupyter?

Comment: no. closing notebook was no help.. tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter and matplotlib are working as you have programmed.

The issue is how you're using `np.linspace()`.

Currently, it is

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,1)
```

If you were to print this out, this is what you would get

```
array([0.])
```

So there is only one `x` value and it is plotted as a single dot.

To plot something, you'll need to change the **third** argument to something else. That is the parameter for `num`, of the number of samples to generate. So having a `1` there produces one point.

So try something like this

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

pl.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Documentation for `np.linspace()` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html