# Jupyter not showing proper matplotlib plots and seaborn plots

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I tried to do a box plot with salary and loan. However its not showing even though the code is correct. And I tried with matplotlib plots, it doesnt work as well.

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wsfy.jpg)

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as image.  Please also provide some test data to create a minimal reproducible example.   You might need to add `plt.show()` at the end of your code, depending on how everything is installed.  First step should be to get a simple matplotlib program working.  Maybe you'll need to reinstall.

Comment: By the way, do you have `%matplotlib inline` as the first line of your notebook? See [How to make IPython notebook matplotlib plot inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline)

Comment: And if you are going to show a screenshot at least show it after you have executed the cell.  The state you screenshotted, you had not even executed the cell with the plot command.